# Terraform RDS DB parameter lookup function

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

The following Terraform `lookup` method does not work. It always renders the default value "immediate".

```
 resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "postgres" {
  name   = var.db_parameter_group_name
  family = "postgres11"

  dynamic "parameter" {
    for_each = var.db_parameters
    content {
      name         = parameter.value.name
      value        = parameter.value.value
      apply_method = lookup(parameter.value, "apply_method", null)
    }
  }
}
```

For example: This is the parameter map I am passing

```
      parameters = [
    {
      name  = "rds.logical_replication"
      value = 1
    }
  ]
```

The output is :

```
parameter {
      + apply_method = "immediate"
      + name         = "rds.logical_replication"
      + value        = "1"
    }
```

`rds.logical_replication` is a `static` parameter and cannot be modified during runtime, it needs DB reboot hence the expected value should be `pending-reboot`

Answer (score 0):

I updated the variable `parameters` from `list of objects` to `map of objects` and passed the apply_method for example:-

```
variable "parameters" {
    description = "A list of Postgres DB parameter"
    type = list(object({
        name         = string
        value        = string
        apply_method = string
    }))
    validation {
        condition = length([
          for parameter in var.parameters : true
            if contains(["immediate", "pending-reboot"], parameter.apply_method)
        ]) == length(var.parameters)
        error_message = "Parameter apply_method can only be immediate or pending-reboot."
    }
  }
```

Added the dynamic block to apply these parameters

```
  dynamic "parameter" {
    for_each = var.db_parameters
    content {
      name         = parameter.value.name
      value        = parameter.value.value
      apply_method = parameter.value.apply_method
    }
  }
```